# Why doesn't SO use MS Bing for search?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search-engine

I am considering search options for an e-commerce website I am building, and wish to understand the rationale behind Stack Overflow's choice of search engine.

Stack overflow has good REST urls, so Bing search seems like it would be ideal - it's free, powerful, and constantly being refined by Microsoft, etc.

Why doesn't SO use Bing for search?

Answer (score 12):

Don't ask why not. Ask **why?**

No, seriously - no one spends time working on something as critical as replacing the search function of a major website *just for the hell of it*. We would need [a *compelling* reason to do so](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/), and I'm not aware of any that involve Bing.

But, [go ahead and use Bing](https://stackoverflow.com/search) if you want - if you find yourself getting *consistently* better results, make a note of that.

Comment: now THAT is a useful post. Thank you. I didn't know that was there. I will look into it further.

Comment: Although, in the OP's defense, I have to say that the Lucene-based search is still … a little crappy. Precision and recall are pretty bad on average, even if I know what question(s) I want to find and most of the keywords I'm looking for.